# iPhone Memory Management: No Need to Clean Up and Release Retained Objects on App Quit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc

Is the following true?

> When the app is about to quit, it's
>   not necessary to clean up the memory
>   by calling release on all your
>   retained objects, because the iPhone
>   OS will reclaim the memory it
>   allocated for your app when you
>   launched it. This is faster and safer
>   than rely on the apps to correctly
>   clean up after themselves. You can
>   verify this by putting an NSLog call
>   (or a debugger breakpoint) in the
>   dealloc method of your application
>   delegate and seeing it's never called.
>
> So, cleaning things up when the app is
>   about to quit is useless. Moreover,
>   you have very limited time before the
>   OS wipes your app out, so don't waste
>   it on cleaning things. Focus on saving
>   your game and any other relevant
>   stuff.

[Source (cocos2d-iphone.org)](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1934)

Comment: Doesn't matter so much on iOS, but on a Mac or PC, if your app was using a bunch of memory pages that have been swapped out to disk, trying to clean up when you quit could mean copying everything back from disk into memory, just to mark it as no longer needed. If you just let the app terminate, the OS knows it can safely just throw all that data away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043):

> Important: When an application
>   terminates, objects may not be sent a
>   dealloc message since the process’s
>   memory is automatically cleared on
>   exit—it is more efficient simply to
>   allow the operating system to clean up
>   resources than to invoke all the
>   memory management methods. This has
>   implications for how you implement a
>   dealloc method—see “Resource
>   Management.”